# Android Emulator Fails to run With Ads

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob, emulation, ads

I am trying to add ads to my app but a error is occuring when i run it

It displays on the Run Screen

> Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1440M emulator:
>   WARNING: Crash service did not start Hax is enabled Hax ram_size
>   0x5a000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>   qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive
>   if=none,index=0,id=system,file=C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86/system.img:
>   could not open disk image
>   C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86/system.img:
>   Could not open
>   'C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86/system.img':
>   Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

From Android studio open Windows->Select Android Virtual Device Manager->Chose your device->Click Edit button->Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb in the Memory Options->Save and run the emulator.

I think this helps you.